# Jusqu'à ce que je sois/soie ?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe

En écrivant ces mots récemment dans une phrase je me suis demandé quelle orthographe était la bonne. Il y a apparemment plus de monde (d'après Google) qui écrit "jusqu'à ce que je sois", or il me semble que "jusqu'à ce que" commande le subjonctif, et donc "soie". S'agit-il peut-être d'une ancienne orthographe qui a été adaptée avec le temps et l'usage ?

Comment: Une recherche rapide donne par exemple ceci : http://www.les-verbes.com/conjuguer.php?verbe=etre

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about conjugaison and can easily be founded in any grammar book.

Comment: Il semblerait que *soie* soit une faute de typographie. Le verbe *seoir* http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/seoir.php n'a pas la conjugaison *seoie* ; Le Littre renvoie à la matière (*soye* en ancien français) www.littre.org/definition/soie --- Quel est le texte où vous avez trouvé *soie* comme conjugaison du verbe *être* ?

Comment: "Jusqu'à ce que j'aie." Ne pas confondre les deux verbes. Valider l'usage avec G s'avère périlleux, surtout en français.

Answer (score 5):

On écrit bel et bien **"Que je sois"**, qui est la forme correcte du subjonctif.